# How to open a window when a window closes?

Tags: javascript, html

My current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="return close()">

<script>
    function close() {
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="return close()">

<script>
    function close() {
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a new window when the website is closed, but it just closes by itself. I am new to web coding, so please do not judge my code

Comment: Why are you trying to open a new window when a website is closed? Are you trying to make it so that a visitor can't leave your website?

Comment: That is around what I am trying to do.

Comment: Not going to happen in modern day browsers. Thank you pop up blockers. 15+ years ago, you would have been able to do this.

Comment: you are trying to trap a user on an endless windows forcing them to just view your page? sounds fishy, illogical and plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This was the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do, however if it's a modal you're looking for, unfortunately they don't exist yet, upon research this was the best solution I had, you could use another script that auto runs to close this page. However, as comments above describe this looks fishy to viewers, and also causes skepticism to google as to why you're doing this for your web page.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onBeforeUnload=" return myFunction()">

<p>Close this window, press F5 or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Click here to go to w3schools.com</a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   window.open("new 2.html"); // or whatever link you'd like, must be .aspx, or .html page etc.

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```